Цикл For и функции. Наполнение матрицы
Напиши функцию get_matrix с тремя параметрами n, m и value, которая будет создавать матрицу(вложенный список) размерами n строк и m столбцов, заполненную значениями value и возвращать эту матрицу в качестве результата работы.
Пункты задачи:

Объявите функцию get_matrix и напишите в ней параметры n, m и value.
Создайте пустой список matrix внутри функции get_matrix.
Напишите первый(внешний) цикл for для кол-ва строк матрицы, n повторов.
В первом цикле добавляйте пустой список в список matrix.
Напишите второй(внутренний) цикл for для кол-ва столбцов матрицы, m повторов.
Во втором цикле пополняйте ранее добавленный пустой список значением value.
После всех циклов верните значение переменной matrix.
Выведите на экран(консоль) результат работы функции get_matix.
def get_matrix (n, m, value):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(n):
        matrix.append(n)
        for j in range(m):
            matrix.append(value)
    print(matrix)
get_matrix(2, 2, 10)


Покажите ваш код и опишите, что не получилось из этого

У меня либо голова перегружена, либо я не так понял задание, но я пытался делать через for i in range(n):

Но именно то, что должно появиться на консоли добиться не могу, из-за чего и думаю, что на стадии написания цикла for делаю ошибку

def get_matrix (n, m, value):
matrix = []
for i in range(n):
matrix.append(n)
for j in range(m):
matrix.append(value)
print(matrix)
get_matrix(2, 2, 10)

У меня получается при первой функции не [[10, 10], [10, 10]] как должно быть, а [2, 10, 10, 2, 10, 10]
[Program finished]

В первом цикле вам надо добавлять не значение, а новый список.
Во втором цикле по индексу первого цикла добавлять значения:
def get_matrix (n, m, value):
    matrix = []
    for i in range(n):
        matrix.append([]) # добавляем список
        for j in range(m):
            matrix[i].append(value) # Пишем в список значение
    print(matrix)
get_matrix(2, 2, 10)

# [[10, 10], [10, 10]]


Ааа, вот оно что. Я что-то этого даже не заметил. Понял, спасибо большое
